# Consumer group ACL of kafka rest

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, acl, kafka-consumer-api

Does consumer group ACL will be checked when using kafka rest to consumer messages?
I configure kafka-rest with:

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
bootstrap.servers=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
client.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
client.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

But the consumer group ACL doesn't be checked.
Since the message in kafka broker is read as ANONYMOUS.
This is used by PLAINTEXT, but I've configured with SASL_PLAINTEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Kafka rest proxy, the ACL that will be checked is for the user running the rest proxy. Not the user submitting the request to the rest proxy unless you do some code changes or use the confluent security plugins.

Comment: However, If I run the rest proxy as user Mike, the user checked when consume messages is still ANONYMOUS.

Comment: For confluent security plugin, I found that Kafka REST Security plugin and ACLs does not work with the V1 consumer API’s since it uses a simple consumer which doesn’t support Kafka Security.
And in V2, no API is used to consume messages.
So I assume there is no way to support consume message with ACL except change the code.

Comment: Ah yeah if you aren't using v2 then security stuff won't apply. What do you mean there's no api to consume messages with v2?

Comment: In v1, use this rest API to consume message from a topic.
"GET /consumers/${group_name}/instances/${instance}/topics/${topic_name}"
No similar API in v2 version.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#get--consumers-(string-group_name)-instances-(string-instance)-records